# Securing REST with Spring Security OAuth

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to configure Spring Security OAuth2 in my Spring Boot application.
Spring Security is also used and configured.

Firstly I've configured both frameworks:

```
  @Configuration
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";


    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .requestMatcher(new OrRequestMatcher(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/rest")
                ))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("clientapp")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .authorities("USER")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                .secret("123456");
        }


    }

}
```

And:

```
 @Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                //.antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/")
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
             .rememberMe()
                 .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                 .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                 .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
                 .and()
             .csrf().disable();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new UserLoginSuccessHandler();
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return tokenRepositoryImpl;
}

@Bean
public SpringSecurityDialect securityDialect() {
    return new SpringSecurityDialect();
}

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
@Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

I have simple REST method, which takes Authenticated User, and print an email.

```
 @RequestMapping("/rest")
public @ResponseBody String home(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    System.out.println("USER : "+ user.getEmail());
    return "Hello "+ user.getUsername();
}
```

So, I am asking /oauth/token in Postman, and I'm getting refresh token and access token fine. Later I'm trying to get data from /rest. Unfortunatelly there is NullPointerException, becouse user is null. What is important, wrong acces token is not authorized (I'm getting proper error from oauth). I'm sure that there is something wrong in configuration, but I don't know where. I was following configuration from :  [this repository](https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth) Any advice would be nice. 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: can you add your postman request?

Comment: Yes, this is my refresh and access token request : http://prntscr.com/a8sup1    and also data request : http://prntscr.com/a8svxt